# Laravel9 でときどきSQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, laravel

local環境でxamppを使い、laravel9を動かしています。

データの一覧から、詳細画面に移動する時に
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
というエラーが発生することがあります。

厄介なのは「発生する時がある」というもので、多くは場合は大丈夫なのですが、10回に1回ぐらいエラーになります。

エラーの `forge'@'localhost` を調べてみると `database.php` に設定された username のようです（ password は指定されていない）。

Laravelが使用するDB設定は `.env` で行っており、username,passwordともに異なります。

---

解決策として `database.php` も `.env` と同じ設定にすれば良いと思うのですが、
もともと「両方同じ設定にしなければならない」のか、
「本来はその必要がない。動作がおかしい」のかが気になります。

なぜ、ときどき、このような現象が発生してしまうのでしょうか？
また、対策としてはどのような方法があるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「本来はその必要がない」です。 `database.php` ては `env()` が使われているはずです。環境がわからないので何が原因かとかは分かりませんが、 `config:cache` などに心当たりはないですか？